# user-defined function for pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

```
def integration(*arg):
    try:
        return np.sum(arg)
    except:
        name = arg
        return name
```

Hi~ This is my function and I want to apply this function to DataFrame like this

```
   k  g  r
0  dd cc hh
1  bb  1  9
2  dd aa ll
3  bb  4  6
```

and a result I got is

```
     g    r
k  
bb   5    15
dd  ccaa  hhll
```

I want 'cc' instead of 'ccaa' and 'hh' instead of 'hhll'. I want to reflect only upper one when length of the input of user-defined funtion exceeds 2 or more.

Comment: I think the example was not appropriate. length of texts in dataframe is not fixed. I just want to use upper text when they are integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
def integration(*arg):
    try:
        if type(np.sum(arg))==string:
            return np.sum(arg)[0:2]
        else:
            return np.sum(arg)
    except:
        name = arg
        return name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, which is more pandaic:

```
# Set the 'k' columns as index
df.set_index('k', inplace=True)

#Then you need to separate numbers from strings so you can change them to integers
df_numeric = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.str.contains(r'^\d+')]).astype(int).groupby(level=0).sum()
df_object = df.apply(lambda x:x[~(x.str.contains(r'^\d+'))])

df = pd.concat([df_numeric, df_object]).reset_index().drop_duplicates('k', keep='first')
```

Output:

```
    k   g   r
0   bb  5   15
1   dd  cc  hh
```